# MPI SEND / RECV ARRAY OF STRINGS in standard C

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, mpi, raspberry-pi4

Okay, so I've been struggling with this problem for a few days. I'm trying to distribute an array of strings to various nodes in my Raspberry Pi 4 computing cluster using its most recent version of openmpi. I figured this was a perfect way to learn how clustering works, but I am completely lost at this point and have no direction. For the current set of code, I'm getting a segmentation fault, but when I follow other sets of instructions, I will sometimes receive only the first character of the first string, and null every other character. Those times are when instead of the current array send line, the first argument would be &(NodeOne[0][0]). Most of these sets of instructions are 6-9 years old.
Does anyone have any ideas to make the code do more than compile?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <mpi.h>

#define NUMC 4

void *set_Stats(void *z);
struct Tickers {
    char ** x;
    int length;
};
struct Tickers getTickers()
{
    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
    char line[300];
    struct Tickers tickers;
    int length = 0;
    char url[60] = "ftp://ftp.nasdaqtrader.com/symboldirectory/nasdaqtraded.txt";
    if(curl)
    {
        FILE *temp = tmpfile();
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void*)temp);
        curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if(temp)
        {
            rewind(temp);
            char c = fgetc(temp);
            while (fgets(line,sizeof(line),temp)) 
            {
                length++;
            }
            rewind(temp);
            length = length - 2;
            tickers.length = length;
            tickers.x = malloc(length * sizeof(char*));
            fgets(line, sizeof(line), temp);
            fgets(line, sizeof(line), temp);
            for(int count = 0; count < length; count++)
            {
                char *string = line + 2;
                int tickLen = strstr(string, "|") - string;
                char sub[tickLen]; 
                tickers.x[count] = malloc(tickLen);
                strncpy(sub, string, tickLen);
                sub[tickLen] = '\0';
                strcpy(tickers.x[count], sub);
                fgets(line, sizeof(line), temp);
            }
            fclose(temp);
        }
    }
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    return tickers;
}
char ** allocate_DD(int rows, int cols)
{
    char *data = (char *)malloc(rows*cols);
    char **array= (char **)malloc(rows*sizeof(char*));
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        array[i] = &(data[cols*i]);
    return array;
}


int main() //Designed for one master, three slaves
{
    int my_id;
    MPI_Init(NULL,NULL);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_id);
    MPI_Status status;
    int firstNodeLength;
    if(my_id == 0) // meaning this process is a host job
    {
        struct Tickers tickers = getTickers();
        int length = tickers.length / 3;
        int remainder = tickers.length % 3;
        char ** NodeOneTicks = allocate_DD(length + remainder, 6);
        //char ** NodeTwoTicks = allocate_DD(length, 6);
        //char ** NodeThrTicks = allocate_DD(length, 6);
        int count = 0;
        int x = 0;
        while(count < length + remainder)
        {
            strcpy(NodeOneTicks[x], tickers.x[count]);
            NodeOneTicks[x][5] = '\0';
            count++;
            x++;
        }
        x = 0;
        firstNodeLength = length + remainder;
        printf("%d\n", firstNodeLength);
        MPI_Send(&firstNodeLength,1, MPI_INT,1,1000,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(NodeOneTicks,firstNodeLength,MPI_CHAR,1,1001,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        
    }
    else // must be slave process
    {
        int myLen;
        int x = 0;
        
        int ierr = MPI_Recv(&myLen,1,MPI_INT,0,MPI_ANY_TAG,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
        printf("%d\n", myLen);
        char ** myTicks = allocate_DD(myLen,6);
        ierr = MPI_Recv(myTicks[0], myLen,MPI_CHAR,0,MPI_ANY_TAG,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
        myTicks[0][5] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", myTicks[0]);
    }
    MPI_Finalize();

}
```

Comment: `NodeOneTicks` is not defined in your code, so I won't comment on the master. On the slave, try `char **myTicks = allocate_DD(myLen, 6); MPI_Recv(myTicks[0], myLen, ...)`. Note you either have to send the null terminating character for each string, or manually add it before `printf()`.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet First, sorry for my late response, another error popped up and it took me a bit to troubleshoot. Second, NodeOneTicks was a mistake in my translation to StackExchange, I changed some of the unessential code so that it was easier to read, but I missed that word, sorry for that. And now, I followed these directions, but I am getting garbage output, I.E, @j(?) when I should be getting something like "A", or "AB". I tried adding the null terminating char for each string in the while loop, and also tested it for just the single string in myTicks. Any ideas?

Comment: post the code that does not work and describe how to run it and the current output vs the expected output.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I've edited the code to display everything how it was originally, minus a few details that I happen to know aren't the problem. I'm fairly sure it has something to do with my recv and send statements, The basic premise is that the master goes to a site and finds the stock tickers of all nasdaq stocks, splits them into sections, and divides them among the slaves (eventually itself too, but that's easier to do later). The getTickers() method seems to work, but only until MPI touches it, exhibited by previous tests where the first tickers would be printed fine on the master.

Comment: Why don’t you send/receive `firstNodeLength * 6`?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Tried that just now, it gave me the error with the garbage output. Is there any chance that the following command is incorrect in order to run the program after compilation? $ mpirun -n 2 --host (two Ips separated by comma), a.out

Comment: you need to fix all the buffer overflows in `getTickers()` (`valgrind` can help you with that, no need for MPI here) and then check the send buffer of the second `MPI_Send()`

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Buffer Overflows? What do you mean by that, and how do you know they're there? Whenever I run that function alone, it returns everything normally.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Nvm, that was a stupid question. I did what you said to and it seems to have fixed the program! Thank you, I will post as an answer momentarily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the problem came from the original array returned by getTickers(). Even though it printed fine when the function was non-mpi, it was overflowed at certain points, rendering the MPI array to be garbage. Thank you to @GillesGouaillardet for helping / basically solving the problem for me!